The return value of memcmp suddenly changed
I am writing tests for various implementations of the memcmp function using the GTest library. To compare my implementations with the memcmp implementation, I also check the memcmp result, but after recent changes to the code, it started giving unexpected results.
Here is my test code. I have commented out all parts that do not affect the problem. I am only providing the uncommented portion.
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std::string_literals;

struct MemcmpTestCase {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    int n;
    int result;
};

std::vector<MemcmpTestCase> testCases {
    { "", "", 0, 0 },
    { "", "1", 0, 0 },
    { "", "1", 20, 0-'1' },
    { "1", "", 0, 0 },
    { "1", "", 20, '1' },
    { "123456789", "", 5, '1' },
    { "123456789", "1234", 5, '5' },
    { "123456789", "12345", 5, 0 },
    { "", "123456789", 5, -'1' },
    { "123", "123", 0, 0 },
    { "123", "123", 1, 0 },
    { "123", "123", 2, 0 },
    { "123", "123", 3, 0 },
    { "123", "123", 4, 0 },
    { "123", "qwe", 0, 0 },
    { "123", "qwe", 1, '1'-'q' },
    { "123", "qwe", 2, '1'-'q' },
    { "123", "qwe", 3, '1'-'q' },
    { "123", "qwe", 4, '1'-'q' },
    { "123_A", "123_B", 0, 0 },
    { "123_A", "123_B", 1, 0 },
    { "123_A", "123_B", 100, 'A'-'B' },
    { "abc\0ABC"s, "abc\0ABZ"s, 6, 0 },
    { "abc\0ABC"s, "abc\0ABZ"s, 7, 'C'-'Z' },
    { std::string(126, '1') + "A", std::string(126, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(127, '1') + "A", std::string(127, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(128, '1') + "A", std::string(128, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(129, '1') + "A", std::string(129, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(254, '1') + "A", std::string(254, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(255, '1') + "A", std::string(255, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(256, '1') + "A", std::string(256, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
    { std::string(257, '1') + "A", std::string(257, '1') + "B", 10000, -1 },
};

void test(const char* s1, const char* s2, const int n, const int result) {
    const static auto error_message = [](const std::string& function, const char* s1, const char* s2, const int n) -> std::string {
        return function + " failed\n"
               "Input strings:\n"
               "  s1: \"" + std::string(s1) + "\"\n"
               "  s2: \"" + std::string(s2) + "\"\n"
               "Length (n): " + std::to_string(n) + "\n";
    };

    const int std_memcmp_result = memcmp(s1, s2, n);

    if (std_memcmp_result != result)
        std::cout << error_message("memcmp", s1, s2, n);
    EXPECT_EQ(std_memcmp_result, result);
}

TEST(MyMemcmpTest, cases) {
    for (const auto& testCase : testCases) {
        test(testCase.s1.c_str(), testCase.s2.c_str(), testCase.n, testCase.result);
    }
}

After adding the line
{ "", "123456789", 5, -'1' }

the test for the scenario
{ "abc\0ABC"s, "abc\0ABZ"s, 7, 'C'-'Z' }

started giving unexpected results:
the memcmp function returns -1 instead of the difference between the first non-matching characters ('C' and 'Z'), as expected.
Here is the output:
[ RUN      ] MyMemcmpTest.cases
memcmp failed
Input strings:
  s1: "abc"
  s2: "abc"
Length (n): 7
../test/my_memcmp_test.cpp:96: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  std_memcmp_result
    Which is: -1
  result
    Which is: -23

[  FAILED  ] MyMemcmpTest.cases (0 ms)

If I comment out any other scenario from the testCases vector, the error disappears.
I know that memcmp does not have to return the difference between the first non-matching characters in the general case. The documentation only specifies the sign of the return value (on Linux).
BUT it is unclear why adding or removing one test scenario affects the return value for another scenario! They should not influence each other!
If the issue is with null terminators, I tried to create the strings as safely as possible. In any case, I do not understand how this can affect the results.

Cannot reproduce.

Maybe std::memcmp rolls a dice and decides to return -1 or 'C'-'Z' depending on the result. This would be a perfectly valid implementation so your tests are incorrect. In reality I expect there is some optimization or pointer invalidation going on which affects your results.

Your test output is misleading because you are not comparing strings, you are comparing memory regions.

@john "This would be a perfectly valid implementation" But it won't be on the market for long.

Adding a new test case shifts the strings in memory, changing their alignment, and functions like memcmp have different algorithms based on size and alignment.

So, the test is broken, because it doesn't conform to the specification of std::memcmp, making additional assumptions, but instead of fixing the test you want to find out the exact implementation details causing the error in the test to suddenly become exposed? Then you probably need to delve into the generated assembly (maybe the compiler decides on a different std::memcmp implementation based on the input data)?

@RaymondChen "Adding a new test case shifts the strings in memory" This may be the case but it's rather unlikely. It's either heap-allocated memory, which is usually malloc-based and so always aligned the same way, or SSO memory, which sits in a vector of strings and is also always aligned the same way. Though miracles do happen, one needs to work hard to establish the case for one.

I cannot reproduce the result you are seeing.  What compiler?  What compiler version?  What compiler flags?  What platform?  (I'm using clang++ Apple 15.0.0, --std=c++17 -pedantic -lgtest -lgtest_main -g, on macOS 14.5.)

You may want to specify your architecture, compiler version, and exact build commands.

Interestingly, you got exactly 32 test cases. I guess the compiler optimizes your loop differently between 32 and 31 iterations. The case that breaks your assumptions is the only one that reaches 7th location. All these are just baseless guess. I would stick with standard guarantees. By the way std::memcmp can be different from memcmp: they are functionally similar, but the later is not std C++.

@Red.Wave I use meson with override_options : ['optimization=0'] for the executable. Also in my case memcmp and std::memcmp are the same. Maybe on other systems not.

As I mentioned, just stick with std guarantees. C++ doesn't have ::memcmp, although on most platforms it compiles. I suggest you compare the disassembly of your program for different cases.

To eliminate any misunderstanding: the test is broken as it relies on a property of a particular implementation of memcpy that is not guaranteed anywhere and can be broken ant any time. The instructive thing here is to find out how exactly this property gets broken, in order to better understand why only guaranteed properties should be relied upon.

If I were to implement std::memcmp, it would return std::strong_ordering.

You are assuming too much about what memcmp returns.
Nowhere in the language specification it is stated the result must be the difference of the values of the first differing byte. Only the sign of the returned value matters (i.e. whether it's 0, negative, or positive).
I your particular case the standard compliant implementation is free to return -23 as well as -1 or even -123124. Moreover it's allowed to change its behavior arbitrarily. Things like memory alignment, size, compliation flags, etc may affect the result.
So don't count on the result being a particluar value, only on whether it's larger, smaller, or equal to 0.
